# How to download Matlab freely?

Tags: matlab

Is Matlab software freely available for downloadin?If yes, from which website, i can download it without much difficulty? I tried to download it fromhttps://in.mathworks.com But it is 30days free trial.

Comment: This is not possible. One alternative you might want to look into is octave. This is an open source version with less toolboxes.

Comment: SciLab, which is an open-source, has a similar syntax to MatLab. You can also look at https://orms.mfo.de/ for more math software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB is not available freely; but GNU Octave, which has the same syntax as MATLAB and much of the functionality, is a free alternative. If you're already skilled in Python, you may wish to look into Sage Math, which is also free, and uses Python syntax.